# read file without intepreting ${}

Tags: ruby, variables, substitution

Friends:

I have a html file on my box that looks like

```
<table id="${id}_pushbutton">

...
...
...
...
</table>

<div id="${id}_background" />
```

When I run them to the following code

```
Dir.glob(fileTypes) do |theFile|
   puts theFile
   data=File.read(theFile)
   puts data
   #output_of_gsub=data.gsub(/::STATIC_TAG_WITH_VER::/, "$static_ver_with_tag")
   #print data
   #puts output_of_gsub
   File.open("/tmp/cool.txt", "w") {|file| file.puts data}
end
```

The output I see is strange

The output looks like

```
id="com.adp.pid:configuration:jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT_toolbar_buttons"
```

so essentilly the ${id} is getting interpreted either by the read or by the puts.

Any suggestion on how to read without interpreting ${id} please ?

-Narahari

Comment: What Ruby interpreter are you using? JRuby?

Comment: Something else other than the code you’ve shown is happening if this is the result you’re seeing. Ruby won’t change the `${}` here, it is treated as pure data (note that even in source code the interpolation syntax is `#{}` not `${}`). Can you provide a minimal code sample that reproduces the problem?